# How to search a 2D String array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public class someClass{
public String[][] board = new String[7][7];

public someClass(){
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I have this in a class I am using, I an struggling to find a way to search through the array and see if the cells left, right, above or below of a particular cell are empty or filled.

I.E `board[4][2]` - how would I look through the array to see if position [4][1],  [4][3], [3][2] and [5][2] are empty or have an element inside of them?

EDIT: I have tries to use nested for loops to look through the array and subtract 1 from the indexes in the loop, however that provides nothing.

Comment: have you tried to do it ?

Comment: Add or subtract one from the first or second index.

Comment: simple math will do it.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned sorry. I initially tried to to nested for loops and looking ai i-1 and j-1 etc, however that displayed nothing. POST EDITED

Comment: Could you post those nested for loops?

Comment: what is the purpose of the method ?

Comment: why do you need to look around (up/down/left/right)?

Comment: It is need to check if the cells around the users selected cell contain an element which is equal

Comment: and if around it there's an element equal to the one just inserted, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Above: [i][j - 1]
Below: [i][j + 1]
Before: [i - 1][j]
After: [i + 1][j]
```

Just make sure to check for out of bounds first.
Then:

```
private boolean isInBounds(int i, int j) {
    return (board.length > 0 && i >= 0 && i < board.length && j >= 0 && j < board[i].length);
}

private boolean isAboveEmpty(int i, int j) { // This might be a little verbose...
    int newJ = j - 1;
    if(isInBounds(i, newJ)) 
        return board[i][newJ].equals(" "); //Above cell is empty
    return true; // out of bounds cells are always empty (or are they?)
}
```

Then repeat for other directions.
Make `board` private too, and let user use a `set` method to set the cells, so you can do your check first.

```
public class Board {
    private String[][] board = new String[7][7];
    ...
    public void set(int i, int j, String value) {
        if(isInBounds(i, j) && isAboveEmpty(i, j) && isBelowEmpty(i, j) && isBeforeEmpty(i, j) && isAfterEmpty(i, j)) {
            board[i,j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your input. I now understand how to do this and how it works :)

Comment: how would I go about doing the opposite of this. So if I have one cell and that becomes surrounded on four sides by other elements then it displays a message?

Comment: After you do ```board[i,j] = value;``` call a method ```checkNeighbours(int i, int j)``` that checks for each of the neighbour cells if they are now surrounded. (```isSurrounded(int i, int j)``` could be another method).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class someClass{

    public String[][] board = new String[7][7];

    public List<Coordinates> findAdjacentCells(final String[][] board, final int x, final int y){
        List<Coordinates> result = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();

        if(x >= 1 && y >= 1) {
            if(y + 1 < board[x].length)
                result.put(new Coordinates(x, y + 1));
            if(y - 1 >= 0)
                result.put(new Coordinates(x, y -1));
            if(x + 1 < board.length)
                result.put(new Coordinates(x+1, y));
            if(x -1 >= 0)
                result.put(new Coordinates(x-1, y));
        }

        return result;
    }
        // Keep track of coordinates
        public class Coordinates {
            int positionX;

            int positionY;

            public Coordinates(int positionX, int positionY) {
                super();
                this.positionX = positionX;
                this.positionY = positionY;
        }

        public final int getPositionX() {
            return positionX;
        }

        public final int getPositionY() {
            return positionY;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do something like the above. I did not know if your board has position 0. Obviously the array does. So you might have to change some of the conditionals around.

Edit: You edited your question and added more code, this might not be relevant anymore.

Comment: thanks for the input I do see what you're doing there for the most part, the list of ifs gives a "method put(String) is undefined for the type List<Board.Coordinates>

Comment: I fixed it, I meant to be creating objects instead of adding the array.

Alternatively instead of using the `Coordinates` class you can make the `List` be a `List<String[][]>` and then do a `result.put(board[x][y + 1])`.

It depends if you need the positions or what's inside the position. Your edit says you are doing a comparison so maybe you just need the values not the coordinates.

Comment: But if x or y = 0, you get an empty list, so you can't get the adjacent cells of first row/collumn cells.

Comment: @JornVernee you are right. We don't know how @Topher wants to handle position 0. I suspect if it's a game board of some sort the corner is 1,1. However if it's 0,0 then the first conditional check `x >= 1` will have to be changed to `x >= 0`.